# Facebook: Fetching status message for a particular date

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to read my status message that was posted at a particular date, say 6 months back. Is it possible to fetch this message using the Facebook Graph APIs?
Thanks,
Saurabh

Answer (score 2):

Yes, check for the since and until parameters.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

until, since (a unix timestamp or any date accepted by strtotime): https://graph.facebook.com/search?until=yesterday&q=orange